# Which of the sentences is more correct grammatically?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Which sentence is correct grammatically?

> I rarely need to visit a doctor except for having regular checkups.

> I rarely need to visit a doctor except to do some checkups.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain your doubt about these sentences, for example have you seen similar constructions being used by native speakers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is better, but 'having' doesn't quite fit.

You might say:

> I rarely need to visit a doctor, except for my/the regular checkups.
>
> Or
>
> I rarely need to visit a doctor, except to have my/the regular
> checkups.

In your second sentence you are checking up on the doctor!

Answer (score 1):

The former.

The latter implies that **you** are doing the checking (with or without the doctor's assistance').

Also, there should be a comma after 'doctor' in the first sentence.